# Как преобразовать элементы ArrayList в строки

Tags: java, массивы, list, коллекции

Задача стоит в том, чтобы удалить все дубли из коллекции, затем отсортировав, преобразовать числа в строки.
Никак не могу сообразить, что не так!

Моя реализация:

```java
public static List<String> task1(List<Integer> source) {
        source = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(source));
        Collections.sort(source);
        String[] numbers = (String[]) source.toArray();
        ArrayList g = new ArrayList(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(numbers)));
        return g;
    }
```

Ошибка:

> `java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.String; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.String; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что нельзя так кастовать лист.

Для версии java 8+:

```
public static List<String> task1(List<Integer> source) {
    return source.stream().distinct().sorted().map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Для версий пониже:

```
public static List<String> task1(List<Integer> source) {
    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(source));
    Collections.sort(temp);

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Integer i : temp) {
        result.add(i.toString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но выдает ошибку!
```java
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: iterable contents differ at index [1], expected: <9> but was: <13>
```

Comment: Да, поправил, сначала сортировка, затем преобразование

Answer (score 0):

Сообразил все же)

```java
public static List<String> task1(List<Integer> source) {
        source = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(source));
        Collections.sort(source);
        List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Object o : source) {
            numbers.add(o.toString());
        }
        return numbers;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
public static List<String> task1(List<Integer> source) {
    TreeSet<Integer> setNums = new TreeSet<>( source );
    List<String> listNums = new ArrayList<>();
    for ( Integer num : setNums ) {
        listNums.add( num.toString() );
    }
    return listNums;
}
```